can I write complex logic inside selctor for action in ngxs?
Let's say I have complex logic inside an action defined in the state. I would like to break it down and use as little code as possible. Is it possible to dispatch another action inside it? If so, is it a good approach?
As an example,
  @Action(BookingEvent)
  event(
    ctx: StateContext<ApiBookingModel>,
    action: BookingEvent
  ): void {
    const state: ApiBookingModel = ctx.getState();
    
    if (
      action.event.action === event.action.NEW
    ) {
     //do something

      return;
    }

    if (action.event.action === event.action.OLD) {
      //do something
      return;
    }

    // Handle rest logic.
    ctx.setState(
        return {
         // do something here
        };
      })
    );
  }

Here, Should I create new action for each if condition check?
